# How to determine source of mysterious server name on my network

Tags: network-security

Over the last few days I have noticed a mysterious (unknown to me) server hostname that shows up on both Ubuntu's Nautilus Network section as well as Windows File Manager network group.  The hostname does not show in the list of clients on my router.  If I double click the hostname icon to try to connect to it I get a connection refused error.  The hostname's appearance is random.

I have non-factory admin and wireless passwords set on my router as well as MAC filtering. Router firewall is on and no unneeded service ports are opened (NFS, etc.).

How can I determine the source of this unknown hostname and how can I close down my network in case this is really someone that has managed to break into my network? Also, if I have explicitly listed the MAC addresses of all my devices how could a non-listed device be able to connect?

Thank you for any comments you can provide.

Comment: I did further investigation on this; turns out the "mysterious" server is due to a hostname on my network with filesharing and netbios over tcp/ip turned on.  I have disabled that so the file share doesn't get broadcasted to the network

Answer (score 0):

Resolved; see previous comment on NetBios over TCP/IP.